# Oracle pd.read_sql DatabaseError: Python value of type tuple not supported

Tags: python, oracle, tuples

I have this code

```
pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT * FROM db WHERE col IN :var",
    con=OracleAccess,
    params={'var': ('var1', 'var2')}
)
```

So I get next erorr

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM db WHERE col IN :var': Python value of type tuple not supported.
```

My code works with Vertica, but I have problem with Oracle.

If I do

```
pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT * FROM db WHERE col IN :var",
    con=OracleAccess, params={'var': 'var1')}
    )
```

It works! It looks like in oracle my variable (params) contained into tuple!? And when I send tuple ('var1', 'var2'), I'll have erorr.

How can I resolve it? Thanks!

I tried send: tuple - errror / list - error / set - erorr / string - works, but I need another variable type :(

This short version. In my query I use more than 1 variable.

Comment: For a WHERE IN clause, you will need to have one bind variable placeholder in the SQL statement for every potential value.  See https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks, it works. This is not exactly what I was looking for.
But as far as I understand, this is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

Now there is only one solution :(

```
pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT * FROM db WHERE col IN (:var1, :var2)",
    con=OracleAccess,
    params={'var1': 'hello', 'var2': 'world'}
)
```